# How can i compile statically libstdc++11?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

I used from [here](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/) for statically compile, and work fine 
`g++ -static-libgcc -L. -o example example.cpp` 
but I want to compile statically via `-std=c++11` flag 
this is my command:
`g++ -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic -o main.o main.cpp` work fine 
but statically not work! 
how can I statically stdlibc++11 ?

Comment: In the second compiler invocation you're using the `-c` flag to tell the compiler to not produce an executable. It may be that you need to read up on "compilation" versus "linking". I think you can find info about that simply by googling it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-static-libstdc++` flag.

```
% cat hello.cc 

#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
%  g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ hello.cc -o hello
% ldd hello
  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdf5f45000)
  libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6ee0f39000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6ee0b90000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563c2b55d000)
```

Without the `-static-*` flags, that would give

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcf2d37000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9c32ba4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9c328a3000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9c3268c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9c322e3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056212766a000)
```